# Restrict adding external users

Tags: alfresco

can I restrict addition of external users to all sites to only one specific administrator, for example **admin_mvlcek**?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

By assigning 'Site Manager' role to the Administrator, you will be able to do that.
Only site-managers can add members to the site.

Comment: Yes, but I need disable this option to all Site Managers and enable just to only one administrator.

Comment: Change the role of current site-manager to collaborator or contributor, and assign Manager role to Administrator only then it will be done.